# I tried to upload file and text data from multipart api but not able to get files even i use multer

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server

I tried to upload file as well as text data from the api,so i have write multipart api for getting file and text data from the res in nodejs for getting file i am using multer module but now i am getting undefined or null in req.files & req.file. I'm trying to upload a file using multer and below are the code snippets :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();

app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('photo'),function (req, res, next) {
    let data = req.body;
    let file = req.file;
    console.log(data)
    console.log(file)
    return res.status(200).send(data)
})
```

Response of this api always return null and undefined

```
functions: Beginning execution of "app"
>  [Object: null prototype] {}
>  undefined
```

and i am passing two parameters from the api

1. photo which is a type of file
2. name parameter which is type of string
   and i have pass this data from Form-data formate

hope anyone help my soon

Comment: Shouldn't it be req.body.file ?

Comment: I tried that but it will not resolve my probleam

Comment: Where have you specified the destination of the file storage received from multer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

Specify the destination file storage location for multer.
The file can be then accessed in the same way as you are doing from `req.file`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to provide the storage location where you can specify storage of your files like this.

```
var upload = multer({ storage: location});

const location = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, './your_folder_name')
}
```